# How to say "for 20 years"?

Tags: preposition, expression

He has lived here for 20 years.
==> Er hat seit 20 Jahren hier gelebt.
Can we also say it like:
==> Er hat 20 Jahre hier gelebt.
?
( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adverbial_phrases
I found Accusative nouns with adverbial meaning: 
Das Kind malte die ganze Zeit Bilder ("The child was painting pictures all the time". Can I apply this to `20 Jahre` here? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me there's a difference. I would use present tense in your first example in German and read the second one as a finished action in the past:

- He has lived here for 20 years (and still does). → Er lebt seit 20 Jahren hier.
- He lived here for 20 years (and does no more). → Er hat 20 Jahre lang hier gelebt. / Er lebte 20 Jahre lang hier.

Comment: I see. You mean the `haben gelebt` and `seit` doesn't mix. Right?

Comment: Right, I'd definitely prefer present tense for this kind of ongoing action. (_Haben gelebt_ would work fine with _seit 2010_, though, but I'd understand that in the second sense as well, i.e. as finished.)

Comment: Is there a distinction between `He has lived here for 20 years` and `He has been living here for 20 years`? I would use the second one instinctively. In my understanding, in the first sentence he does **not** live here anymore.

Comment: I think `He has lived here for 20 years` can mean both `he still lives here` and `he doesn't live here any more`. But if we say `He has had lived here for 20 years`, it definately means he no longer lives here. I know most Americans say in this situtation(when he still lives), `He has been living here for 20 years`. It's their habit.

Comment: @DonHolgo Yes, thanks for clarifying it to me. I know how to use `since`, looks like `seit`is similar to `since`.

Comment: Fully agree with adhominem.

Answer (score 1):

You can really say both and yes I think the link you provide applies.

I would recommend using the second sentence however.
The first sentence somehow seems clumsy and redoubling (implicitly) the time
and I think I've heard the first sentence also in regional dialects (not sure).

Best,
SG

Comment: No problem. Maybe you should also accept the answer in StackExchange.

Comment: I chose your answer first, but later found DonHolgo's answer gave me more insight as to the use of `seit 20 Jahren` and `20 Jahre` relating to the use of present form and present perfect form. Your answer is almost as good. But, sorry for the change..

Comment: Chan Kim: Whatever is better for you. Best wishes, SG